# Хранение всех выполненых команд в bash history

Tags: linux, bash, history, .bashrc

Как можно хранить историю всех выполненых команд в `.bash_history`, т. е. даже в случае, если они были введены с пробелом вначале?

Comment: Не вводить их с пробелом в начале

Comment: @AlexeyTen гений

Answer (score 4, accepted):

За это отвечает переменная окружения [`HISTCONTROL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTCONTROL). Если в ней содержится значение `ignorespace` или `ignoreboth`, то команды, начинающиеся с пробела, не добавляются в историю.

Чтобы добавлять в историю все команды, почистите значение этой переменной:

```bash
export HISTCONTROL=
```

Проверьте наличие этой переменной в вашем `.bashrc` и поправьте ее в этом файле, если она там задана.

Согласно [документации](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTCONTROL), `HISTCONTROL` может содержать следующие значения, разделенные символом двоеточия:

- `ignorespace` — не добавлять команду в историю, если она начинается с пробела
- `ignoredups` — не добавлять команду, если она совпадает с предыдущей
- `ignoreboth` — то же, что и `ignorespace:ignoredups`
- `erasedups` — все команды, которые совпадают с текущей командой, будут удалены из истории перед добавлением текущей команды